# Using a generic protocol type inside of another generic protocol type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to figure out how to use a protocol that has a Self or associated type requirement inside of another protocol. Consider the following example:

```
protocol SortBy {
    static var values: [Self] { get }
    var title: String { get }
}

protocol Filter {
    var sortBy: SortBy { get set }

    init(_ filter: Self)
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    static func != (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}
```

I know that since `SortBy` contains a reference to `Self`, I can only use it as a generic constraint. What I don't know is if there is any Swift magic I can do to allow what I'm trying to achieve?

Ultimately I want to use the protocols for an example as follows:

```
enum Sort: SortBy {
    case sort1
    case sort2

    static var values: [Sort] {
        return [
            .sort1,
            .sort2
        ]
    }

    var title: String {
        switch self {
            case .sort1:
            return "Sort 1"

            case .sort2:
            return "Sort 2"
        }
    }
}

struct FilterExample: Filter {
    var sortBy: SortBy

    init(_ filter: FilterExample) {
        ...
    }

    static func == (lhs: FilterExample, rhs: FilterExample) -> Bool {
        ...
    }

    static func != (lhs: FilterExample, rhs: FilterExample) -> Bool {
        ...
    }
}
```

And in case it matters, I'm using Swift 3.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

associatedTypes and generics should be able to get what you want. That said, you should take a look at the [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) and [Comparable](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/comparable) protocols. It looks like you're trying to do something related and adoption of those may help you. E.g. adoption of Equatable means you only have to implement `==` and you get `!=` for free.

```
protocol SortBy {
    static var values: [Self] { get }
    var title: String { get }
}

protocol Filter {

    associatedtype SortByType: SortBy
    var sortBy: SortByType { get set }

    init(_ filter: Self)
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    static func != (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

struct FilterExample<T: SortBy>: Filter {

    var sortBy: T

    init(_ filter: FilterExample<T>) {
        self.sortBy = filter.sortBy
    }
    static func == (lhs: FilterExample, rhs: FilterExample) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    static func != (lhs: FilterExample, rhs: FilterExample) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.